# How can I fix the Chromium render process crash problem in Flutter Headless WebView on Android 13?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-inappwebview

Can anyone help me fix these errors on Android 13? Not every device has this issue, but some Redmi and Poco devices are showing this error.

Note: I am new to Flutter, so if you can help me with the Bluetooth and getForceDark() error, that would be appreciated.

```
W/cr_media( 9967): BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission is missing.
W/cr_media( 9967): registerBluetoothIntentsIfNeeded: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
W/le.test_project( 9967): Accessing hidden field Landroid/content/pm/ApplicationInfo;->primaryCpuAbi:Ljava/lang/String; (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/VideoCapabilities( 9967): Unsupported mime image/vnd.android.heic
2
W/VideoCapabilities( 9967): Unrecognized profile/level 0/3 for video/mpeg2
W/cr_WebSettings( 9967): getForceDark() is a no-op in an app with targetSdkVersion>=T
I/flutter ( 9967): Instance of 'Future<String?>'
E/chromium( 9967): [ERROR:aw_browser_terminator.cc(156)] Renderer process (11888) crash detected (code -1).
```

I just tried this simple function but app stop workng.

```
Future<String?> httpRequest(String url, int method) async {
  String? html;
  HeadlessInAppWebView? headlessInAppWebView;
  headlessInAppWebView = HeadlessInAppWebView(
    initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(url)),
    onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
      html = await controller.getHtml();
      headlessInAppWebView?.dispose();
    },
  );
  headlessInAppWebView.run();
  return html;
}
```